# Any low-cost Virtual Private Servers able to run GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

I'm looking at virtual private server hosting options for GeoServer. At a recent conference, the most often cited  cost of such servers was around $50/month. I've found a few places that advertize VPSs for much less, some as low as $17/month. The specs appear to be adequate for installing and running GeoServer, at least for my initial experimental needs. The reason I'm looking at the lower cost options is that I'm not going to be generating any income here.

I'm curious to hear from others that may have tried this ultra-low-cost GeoServer route. How did it work out for you, and if so, which low-cost VPS providers seemed to work out the best, if any did at all?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just deleted one of my Amazon EC2 instances where I had GeoServer running on it.  You can spin up a micro instance for 2 or 3 cents / hour depending on linux/windows.  But I only use them to play, I couldn't comment on using them in a production environment (you would probably have to use a larger instance which costs more per hour).  If you are just developing on them, you can just start them when you need them and stop them when your done and that will save you some cash (you can do this easily in a batch file).

Also, don't terminate the instances--that removes them permanently!

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home

Pricing: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

**Update**: There are some opengeo amazon machine instances already present...you might be able to launch an existing AMI (although it didn't have a micro-instance option for me).

<strike>**Another Update** I found this while trying to find out information on the existing AMIs:

http://blog.opengeo.org/2010/09/13/opengeo-suite-community-edition-on-amazon-web-services/</strike>

Comment: i think I left one instance running last month--my s3 + ec2 + amazon mp3 purchases were all under $20.

Comment: And it looks like as of today, you can play for free! http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Chad - Signed up for my free AWS this morning.

Comment: Seems like you can get better performance on rackspace tho: http://www.thebitsource.com/featured-posts/rackspace-cloud-servers-versus-amazon-ec2-performance-analysis/

Comment: Excellent tutorial on setting up GeoServer on micro instance: http://imperialwicket.com/aws-configuring-a-geo-spatial-stack-in-amazon-linux

Answer (score 7):

I really like http://linode.com
I run http://postgisonline.org on their smallest VPS which costs 19.95$.
It is a Xen virtualized server. You can choose from a lot of different Linux distros, and there is plenty of great guides how to install and manage the server.

I have not tried to run GeoServer on it, my application uses MapServer to produce the maps.

Regards
Nicklas

Comment: Linode also pro-rata their offerings, meaning you can spin up new machines, use them for a period, then bin them and only pay for the time it was up.  I haven't run Geoserver on a Linode, but I do run some other stuff and can't fault it.  I'm not a linux guru either.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Linode mentioned above, [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) is another popular low-cost VPS service.  You should be able to run GeoServer on any VPS as you should have control over what software is installed.

Comment: Some more comments on Slicehost: http://www.quora.com/What-factors-should-one-consider-if-deciding-between-Slicehost-and-Rackspace-Cloud

Answer (score 4):

Starting a month ago, Amazon AWS is offering a free instance of their basic server for 1 year.  I have installed PostGIS and Geoserver on it with no issues, perfect for a sandbox or just testing the waters.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for linode. I've got a friend that's running GeoDjango w/ PostGIS comfortably with it.

If you're really interested in getting a rock-bottom deal, you can always keep one eye on http://www.lowendbox.com/. I haven't used any of their advertised specials but they seem to keep a pretty current list of deals on VPS.

Comment: +1 for linode too. I have one project running on Linode currently, i deployed Django, Geoserver and Postgis on one VPS. So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

Although more pricey than Linode and Slicehost, [HostGIS](http://www.hostgis.com/home/) might be also worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late but for new GIS developers who have the same question like me can also have a look at http://www.a2hosting.com/vps-hosting so far found this hosting company provides the cheapest VPS but sure if any one has depolyed opengeo suite on it ... let me know if you try it...thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [F(x) Data Cloud](https://fxdata.cloud) for low cost Virtual Private Servers to run GeoServers.

The basic reason is that the prices are very low for the servers,Starting prices are $1.99/Month and you can have multiple option for operating system.Plans can even be customized and you get custom size SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest of hosting cheap and required to pay features. In that you have required  a limit of hosting plane that only pay and another time cancel of your subscription. [nexahost](https://www.nexahost.com/) a platform provide of best hosting planes.